# Android View nullPointerException cause by setVisibility() method

Tags: java, android

I'm have an issue with changing the visibility of my buttons.  Whenever I use the setVisibility() method I get a nullPointerException.  Here is the error I get:

```
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at com.android.Rides.RideTracking.onClick(RideTracking.java:307)
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-08 15:59:02.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2807):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code:

```
        public View btnStart = null;
        public View btnPause = null;
        public View btnResume = null;

        case R.id.btnPauseRide:
            mLoggerServiceManager.pauseGPSLogging();

            setResult( RESULT_OK, intent );
            btnPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnResume.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.btnResumeRide: 
            mLoggerServiceManager.resumeGPSLogging();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

            btnResume.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        default:
                            break;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because

```
 public View btnPause = null;
```

you set the `button` to `null`. You need to assign it. Assuming you have already called `setContentView()` and the `button` is in that `layout`

```
btnPause = (Button) findViewwById(R.id.button_id);
```

You have all of your `buttons` set to `null` then trying to call a method on them, `setVisibility()`, which will return `null` every time

If you are wanting to hide the `Button` that is pressed then you can just do

```
    case R.id.btnPauseRide:
        mLoggerServiceManager.pauseGPSLogging();

        setResult( RESULT_OK, intent );
        btnPPauseRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnResume.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
```

instead of creating these new `View`s unless you have something else going on

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the variable you are trying to access is not set. Check your onCreate method if you set it and actually find it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the null pointer exception because you are assigning the view as null.  Instead, try initializing the View via either:

```
public View btnPause = findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
```

or....

```
public View btnPause = new View(this);
```